# iOS - ArcGIS iOS SDK and Google Map iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps, duplicates, arcgis

I am currently trying to integrate google map street view features onto arcgis base map. But it causes 6 duplicate symbols error when I add `-ObjC`, `-all_load` linker flags. These flags are required.

Error statement,

```
ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
```

Is there a way to remove the duplicate symbols or is there any alternative way to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Google map API and ArcGiS API both cannot be added to an iOS project at the same time as they use the same libraries internally. Therefore you are getting error for duplicate symbols.

Comment: is there a way to remove it or avoid it

Comment: I donot think that you have access to ArcGIS API code files as it is not open source. Therefore there is no way to avoid this.

Comment: Ok thanks. Even with duplicate symbols error. i still can install on the real device. Will it cause problem or error if i ignore it

Comment: Can you explain how do you run your app on device if there is big linker error ?